# Is there a way to Display Text at most right of the Navigation Drawer Single Menu Item - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

[image]

**Greetings!**

I am trying to achieve the following design in my Material navigation Drawer.

I have tried all the solutions I can find online but no luck. It will be really helpful, if someone can guide me.
**Thanks**

Here is my Menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_item_1"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu_home"
            android:title="@string/home" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu_profile"
            android:title="@string/profile" />


        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_favourites"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu_favourite"
            android:title="@string/favourites" /> 

    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step - 1:**  Create layout for your custom view `consumer_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

**Step - 2:** Add the `layout` to your menu item

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/consumer_layout"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_profile"
    android:title="@string/profile" />
```

**Step - 3:** Find menu item and set text:

```
TextView view = (TextView) navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_profile).getActionView();
view.setText("Consumer");
```

If you don't want to use custom `TextView` then skip **Step - 1** and modify **Step - 2** like below:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView" 
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_profile"
    android:title="@string/profile" />
```